# Getting gyp err

Tags: yarnpkg, node-gyp, sass-loader

I'm building a web app using react and I'm about to style it. Then I need to install scss-loader and node-sass to teach webpack how to work with my scss styles files but after I ran this:

```
yarn add sass-loader@6.0.6 node-sass@4.5.3
```

I got a very long error

```
yarn add sass-loader@6.0.6 node-sass@4.5.3



[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check.
Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > react-modal@2.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning " > react-modal@2.2.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0
|| ^15.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.16.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\IT\\Desktop\\react-course-projects\\indecision-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\IT\Desktop\react-course-projects\indecision-app\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

my node and npm version are

```
node -v 10.16.0
npm -v 6.9.0
```

Thank you all wonderful programmers as you help me look into this.

Comment: Have you updated node recently? Try reinstalling node-sass: `npm remove node-sass`, `yarn install`

Comment: thanks i just install windows-build-tools and run the command again then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu20 and this fixed the issue for me

```
sudo apt -y install python2
```